# Whilh SQL Structure Is Better?

Tags: sql

I have 2 Option For Creating a SQL stucture

For example I need column **Code**, **Name**, and **Religion** :

**Option 1 :**

```
+=======+========+=============+
+ Code  + Name   + Religion_id +
+=======+========+=============+
+ 1     + A      +  1          +
+ 2     + B      +  2          +
+ 3     + c      +  2          +
+=======+========+=============+

+=============+===============+
+ Religion_id + religion_name +
+=============+===============+
+  1          + Caaaaaa       +
+  2          + Daaaaaa       +
+=============+===============+
```

**Option 2 :**

```
+=======+========+
+ Code  + Name   +
+=======+========+   For Master File
+ 1     + A      +
+ 2     + B      +
+ 2     + C      + 
+=======+========+

+=============+===============+
+ Religion_id + religion_name +
+=============+===============+    For Master File
+  1          + Caaaaaa       +
+  2          + Daaaaaa       +
+=============+===============+

+=======+=============+
+ Code  + Religion_id +
+=======+=============+    For Transaction File
+ 1     +  1          +
+ 2     +  2          +
+ 3     +  2          +
+=======+=============+
```

I have done database for around 1 year.

But after I learned at college, I learned that in master file cannot have duplicate data.

In **Option 1** there is a duplicate value such as 2 people with same religion. So They create the structure like **Option 2**.

but IMO **Option 2** will take a lot of memory space with a thousand records than **Option 1**.

**My Question is : Which One is the best practice for creating the SQL Structure?**

**EDit: 1 Name can only has 1 religion**

Comment: Is Code the primary key in both tables in Option2? And are there always both fields (Name and Religion_id) existent for one "code"? There is an error in your Option 2 i think, code 2 has two names.

Comment: @Argeman in Option 2, first table name is the name for a person, second table is the name for the religion, because each religion has an ID

Comment: @Argeman The Primary key is Code(person id) and religion ID

Comment: Okay, but you didn't answer the most important part: does every person have exactly one name and exactly one religion? Then it is Option 1, otherwise Option 2. Just like JW already answered. I would accept his answer or ask him if something is still unclear. What you are searching for is "normalization" by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the relationship between the two tables.

Option 1 is  a `One-to-many` Relationship wherein `Religion` can contain on many `Names`. But if the relationship is `Many-to-Many`, wherein a certain `Name` can have multiple `Religions` and that religion can be on many `Name`, go for Option 2 since it uses association table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 1 Name can Only has 1 religion.
in option 2 won't it use much memory space when the data is thousands?

Comment: if that's the case, go for `option 1`.

Comment: In option 1, which one is the master and transaction file?

Comment: there is not. All I can say is that table `Name` is dependent on table `Religion`.